# Addresses stored in SQL server have many small variations(errors)

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have a table in my database which stores packing slips and their information.  I'm trying to query that table and get each unique address.  I've come close, but I still have many near misses and I'm looking for a way to exclude these near duplicates from my select.

Sample Data

```
CompanyCode   CompanyName                     Addr1                City         State   Zip
10033         UNITED DIE  CUTTING & FINISHIN  3610 HAMILTON AVE    CLEVELAND    Ohio    44114
10033         UNITED DIE CUTTING & FINISHING  3610 HAMILTON AVE    CLEVELAND    Ohio    44114
10033         UNITED DIE CUTTING & FINISHING  3610 HAMILTON AVE.   CLEVELAND    Ohio    44114
10033         UNITED DIE CUTTING & FINISHING  3610 HAMILTON AVENUE CLEVELAND    Ohio    44114
10033         UNITED DIECUTTING & FINISHING   3610 HAMILTON AVE    CLEVELAND    Ohio    44144
10033         UNITED FINISHING                3610 HAMILTON AVE    CLEVLAND     Ohio    44114
10033         UNITED FINISHING & DIE CUTTING  3610 HAMILTON AVE    CLEVELAND    Ohio    44114
```

And all I want is 1 record.  Is there some way I can get the "Average" record?  Meaning, if most of the records say CLEVELAND instead of CLEVLAND, I want my 1 record to say CLEVELAND.  Is there any way to par this data down to what I'm looking for?

Desired Output

```
 CompanyCode   CompanyName                     Addr1                City         State   Zip
 10033         UNITED DIE CUTTING & FINISHING  3610 HAMILTON AVE    CLEVELAND    Ohio    44114
```

Comment: And what is the best way to format a table in StackOverflow?

Comment: Is there some SQL function like the statistical "Mode" for words?  i.e. something that will return the most common value for a field?

Comment: You could do a groupby on each column to get the most common value, but that won't help because it won't be the most common value for a given address, it'll be the most common address ever entered.

Comment: @Neil Barnwell- I could make it the most used in a subset if I first do a subquery (or store a previous query in a temp table).  In fact, that could work.  I may have to use Dynamic SQL and loops to build my query at runtime, but if I structure it right it could work.

Comment: It could as long as the one you compare it to is a "known good" value.  My current feeling is: "Here be dragons".  It's just not an easy problem to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use subqueries in the select statement
Try this query:

```
 select CompanyCode,
    (select top 1 CompanyName from Table1 where CompanyCode=X.CompanyCode 
     group by CompanyName order by count(*) desc) CompanyName,
    (select top 1 Addr1 from Table1 where CompanyCode=X.CompanyCode 
     group by Addr1 order by count(*) desc) Addr1,
    (select top 1 City from Table1 where CompanyCode=X.CompanyCode 
     group by City order by count(*) desc) City,
    (select top 1 State from Table1 where CompanyCode=X.CompanyCode 
     group by State order by count(*) desc) State,
    (select top 1 Zip from Table1 where CompanyCode=X.CompanyCode 
     group by Zip order by count(*) desc) Zip
from    Table1 X
group by CompanyCode
```

Comment: What if the first record is one with a typo or the companycode is mis-typed?

Comment: Note that it´s not the first record of the table, it´s the first record grouped by the variable and ordered by count(*) desc. In that way it´s the most comon value of this variable in each case. Yes, it assumes that the CompanyCode is well typed.

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand.  This might be helpful, I'll try soon.  How many records should this yeild?

Comment: You answered my question perfectly.  Of course, I didn't ask the question with all the details (I just realized something), so I'm still looking for a solution to the actual problem.

Comment: So here's the more of it: there may be more than 1 legitimate address per companycode.  All I want to filter out is the ones that are almost the same.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to struggle.  Personally I think I'd consider having a process that tries to update the data in the database and correct it.

You could change the system that inputs the data (or if that's not possible, have an external process that runs over the data once it's in the db) that does something like the following:

1. Against known lists of things like towns/states/countries etc to catch typos.
2. For known regular mistakes and abbreviations.  E.g. "Avenue"/"Ave." or "Street"/"St." and normalises the values.
3. Change the input system to do this kind of validation and/or provide the users with an address search/validation UI that allows then to search for an address given some known values (zip/postal code etc).  You can buy data like this from various suppliers depending on where you are in the world.

If this all works (I doubt you'll get 100% unless you provide a mechanism whereby those things that can't be auto-corrected are flagged for human intervention), then your reporting is as simple as `SELECT DISTINCT`...

Comment: Well, I can't modify the data directly.  But I suppose I could save the data into a temporary table and then modify that.  How would I go about number 2?

Comment: For option 2, you'd be effectively doing `REPLACE()`-style code that replaces variants with a known value (i.e. "St.", "St" all replace with "Street" either before the data arrives in the db, or with some kind of scheduled/message-driven process that updates the table after it's already got in there (yuck).

Comment: So you don't see a way to do this in SQL only?

Comment: You could use insert triggers, though you'd have to be efficient or you'll slow your inserts right down.  If you were restricted to doing this in the database, I'd have insert triggers on the table that write a message to another table, and have a separate scheduled process (using the SQL Agent if you're using SQL Server) that runs a stored procedure to "fix" the data relating to each message and deletes the message.  I hate this solution (we do it all the time at work) because I prefer to write C# code and keep my business logic out of the database, but when needs must...

Comment: There are some commercial batch tools that will standardize using USPS your addresses. Then doing the match for duplicates will be a no-brainer.

Answer (score 1):

Is it one-time job, I hope? It's impossible unless you can explain (in SQL terms) why first record is what you need. As an temporary solution I'd suggest following query

```
select C1.* from Company C1, 
(select CompanyCode, min(CompanyName) as CompanyNameSelected 
   from Company
   group by CompanyCode) C2
where 
   C1.CompanyCode = C2.CompanyCode and 
   C1.CompanyName = C2.CompanyNameSelected;
```

You could use any of aggregation functions instead of `min` (returning CompanyName of course), or even write your own stored function, but the only thing is needed - you have to explain in query language why record #1 is better than #2.