# Find duplicate values in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, distinct

```
Address(COLUMN NAME)
100 INDONIA DR  CAMP ROAD 600618
100 INDONIA  CAMP ROAD 600618
1009 CLARK STREET  STEFEN ROAD 876257
1009 S MAIN ST  HOLAN 654636
1007 OAKIRA ST  FARAL DELLS 600106
1007 OAKIRA STREET  FARAL DELLS 600106
19 SUN MARTIN ST  BELGIN 122010
145 CHARLES ST  JHARVAND 110012
1007 S SUPERIOR ST.  BILTON 625017
1007 S. SUPERIOR STREET  BILTON 625017
187 HOWARD STREET  VIRLITIN 220120
```

i need to find out how to make distinct for this column. the values are same address but the spelling is different in some rows.

```
Address
100 INDONIA DR  CAMP ROAD 600618
100 INDONIA  CAMP ROAD 600618
1009 CLARK STREET  STEFEN ROAD 876257
1009 S MAIN ST  HOLAN 654636
1007 OAKIRA ST  FARAL DELLS 600106
1007 OAKIRA STREET  FARAL DELLS 600106
19 SUN MARTIN ST  BELGIN 122010
145 CHARLES ST  JHARVAND 110012
1007 S SUPERIOR ST.  BILTON 625017
1007 S. SUPERIOR STREET  BILTON 625017
187 HOWARD STREET  VIRLITIN 220120
```

Here's my try.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Ltrim(Rtrim([Address])) AS Address
FROM   [Vigness].[dbo].[Test]
WHERE  Address LIKE '% %'
       AND Len(Address) > 0
ORDER  BY 1
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. We usually ask the OPs (you) to provide us what you have tried to do until now. Have you tried any query or something? Can you show us your efforts?

Comment: "SELECT Distinct LTRIM(RTRIM([Address])) As Address
  FROM [Vigness].[dbo].[Test]
  Where
  Address Like '% %' And
   LEN(Address)>0   
  Order by 1 ". I tried the above Query but its not properly filtering the values.

Comment: @Vicky, do all values begin and end with a numeric (so the pattern is always "numeric value varchar numeric" ?

Comment: No i have different Address. the above values are just a sample picked randomly from the table.

Comment: I need to Filter the data using only address field. to find the correct datas

Comment: select other columns, max(address) group by other columns.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question here about address standardizations using soundex in SQL Server

[SQL address data is messy, how to clean it up in a query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951039/sql-address-data-is-messy-how-to-clean-it-up-in-a-query)

The relevant function is `soundex()`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: It's appears it will.  From MSDN for the input value:
character_expression
Is an alphanumeric expression of character data.

Comment: If data is alpha numeric then it will return `0000`

Comment: But how can i find the duplicate values using soundex.